# Opentelemetry configuration for auto and manual instrumentation

Tags: java, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

In an application auto instrumented with the javaagent, it looks possible to add manual instrumentation according to the documentation.

- For auto instrumentation, I know we can use environment variables or system properties. For instance `OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=logging` to enable logging exporter for traces.
- Now, for manual instrumentation, we should instantiate somehow a `OpenTelemetrySdk` and register a `SdkTracerProvider` (configured either manually or via env variables/system properties as well)

What happens if auto instrumentation configures some exporters (logging for instance) and manual instrumentation define another one (OTLP/HTTP for instance)?

Is there a unique instance of `OpenTelemetry` in this case or two living each in "different contexts"?

**Several questions but related to the same topic: how manual and auto instrumentation live together?**

*(For additional context, I'm looking to have manual metrics, auto instrumented traces and potentially some manual traces as well)*

Answer (score 0):

*Even though the question is a bit broad, let me try to give some hints to users that would read it.*

1. Auto instrumentation with the java agent and manual instrumentation may live together with two distinct `OpenTelemetry` instances. The java agent would instantiate and register the global instance (`GlobalOpenTelemetry`) and your code may instantiate another `OpenTelemetry` but not register it as the global one.

   - **This will work but should probably be avoided as long as possible** because you may encounter situations where some telemetry data would be "attached" to one `OpenTelemetry` instance or the other and you'd loose "correlation". For instance, with traces, you may get two traces instead of one.
   - In this scenario, manual instrumentation may be configured either entirely manually by instantiating a `OpenTelemetrySdk` with manual configs, or by using environment variables / system properties as the java agent is doing thanks to `opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure` dependency.
2. Another approach, better when possible, is to use the java agent, configure it with environment variables / system properties and then **reuse the global instance in your code** thanks to `GlobalOpenTelemetry.get()`.

   - If you're using a DI framework (Spring, Guice...), your code should rely on having a `OpenTelemetry` instance and use your framework to provide it by calling `GlobalOpenTelemetry.get()` at startup.